# Optimize Postgres Query with Indexes for large amounts of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, optimization, postgresql-performance

I've got a database, `posts` that has about 20 million rows in it. I'm trying to narrow down the posts for a paginated list using the following query:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
WHERE "posts"."source_id" IN (14790, 14787, 32928, 14796, 14791, 15503, 14789, 14772, 15506, 14794, 15543, 31615, 15507, 15508, 14800)
AND "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

(There are about 3.3 million rows that match the `source_id` in the query)

When I do so, it takes about 60s, and I get the following `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ([see on depesz](http://explain.depesz.com/s/glky)):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."source_id" IN (14790, 14787, 32928, 14796, 14791, 15503, 14789, 14772, 15506, 14794, 15543, 31615, 15507, 15508, 14800) AND "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL O
RDER BY external_created_at desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2530223.38..2530223.63 rows=100 width=1040) (actual time=66564.583..66564.616 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2530223.38..2534981.19 rows=1903125 width=1040) (actual time=66564.571..66564.594 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: external_created_at
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 89kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=35499.76..2457487.31 rows=1903125 width=1040) (actual time=279.640..64496.330 rows=1674072 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[])) AND (deleted_at IS NULL))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4640188
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_on_posts_partial_source_id_with_order  (cost=0.00..35023.98 rows=1903125 width=0) (actual time=275.922..275.922 rows=1674072 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[]))
 Total runtime: 66564.962 ms
(10 rows)
```

This is the index that it is using:

```
CREATE INDEX index_on_posts_partial_source_id_with_order ON posts USING btree (source_id) WHERE (deleted_at IS NULL);
```

It seems that the `Recheck Cond` is the slowest thing about this query. Everything I see about Recheck Conditions involve upping the memory that postgres uses because the data is "[lossy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106267)" but I'm not seeing anything like that in my query plan.

Any recommendations as to how I can speed this up?

It seems like somehow getting rid of the Recheck, or somehow ordering by `external_created_at` will be my best bets.

Edit: I am using postgres version `9.3.4`. Here is the posts table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    source_id integer,
    message text,
    image text,
    external_id text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    external text,
    like_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    comment_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    external_created_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp without time zone,
    poster_name character varying(255),
    poster_image text,
    poster_url character varying(255),
    poster_id text,
    "position" integer,
    location character varying(255),
    description text,
    video text,
    rejected_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_by character varying(255),
    height integer,
    width integer
);
```

Comment: Edit your question, and include the CREATE TABLE statement for "posts" and the PostgreSQL version. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thanks! Edited my question to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning a couple million rows for a paginated list. Think hard about the wisdom of returning data for that many pages. Also, think hard about whether you need all the columns. I doubt that you do.

I built a rough table and inserted about 10 million random(ish) rows into it. My query plan using PostgreSQL 9.4 is roughly similar to yours.

```
"Limit  (cost=138609.10..138609.35 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=1410.012..1410.038 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=138609.10..140344.25 rows=694059 width=24) (actual time=1410.010..1410.026 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: external_created_at"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=12217.47..112082.66 rows=694059 width=24) (actual time=374.393..919.687 rows=3000000 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[])) AND (deleted_at IS NULL))"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=16217"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_on_posts_partial_source_id_with_order  (cost=0.00..12043.95 rows=694059 width=0) (actual time=370.593..370.593 rows=3000000 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[]))"
"Planning time: 0.264 ms"
"Execution time: 1410.097 ms"
```

Adding an index to external_created_at dropped the execution time by a factor of about 470.  But I don't have the same distribution of values that you have.

```
create index on test.posts (external_created_at);
analyze test.posts;
explain analyze
select * from test.posts
where source_id in (14790, 14787, 32928, 14796, 14791, 15503, 14789, 14772, 15506, 14794, 15543, 31615, 15507, 15508, 14800)
and deleted_at is null
order by external_created_at desc limit 100 offset 0;
```

```
"Limit  (cost=0.43..131.43 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=0.219..2.992 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan Backward using posts_external_created_at_idx on posts  (cost=0.43..900991.48 rows=687808 width=24) (actual time=0.216..2.976 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[])))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 350"
"Planning time: 0.302 ms"
"Execution time: 3.024 ms"
```

Comment: Woah yeah, that sped it up [significantly](http://explain.depesz.com/s/ax6)! Much more than I would have expected. However, two follow ups. If I have an index on `source_id`, as I should, for other queries, and it being a foreign key, the planner favors that index and it is much slower. Additionally, when I query for different sources like [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/ZuZ), the results are slow again. I'm not sure why it would be different, apart from that one having more varied external_created_at.

Comment: Did you update statistics after creating an index? (`analyze posts;`)

Comment: Yep, updated statistics, with `VACUUM ANALYZE posts`.

Comment: Actually, it's looking like the reason this was so much quicker was not because of the index, but rather because I ran `CLUSTER posts` on the `external_created_at `index. Unfortunately, running cluster in production is difficult as it has a global lock.

Comment: Compare the performance of `select source_id...` with the performance of `select *...`.